# Object type of email synchronized with Outlook

Tags: email, einstein, salesforce-for-outlook

I use Einstein Activity Capture to synchronize emails between Office and Salesforce.

When I send an email to a contact from Outlook, the email is synchronize with the contact in Salesforce.

Unfortunately, the email in Salesforce is not an email message object (it's not the same URL than an email message).
What is that object?
I need to develop an apex trigger on it but I am afraid it is not possible.

This is the url of the email in Salesforce:

> https://***.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_activities__unifiedEmailStencilWrapper?c__orgThreadId=%3CPR0P264MB23449AC11F2D943BFE3DE725B4469%40PR0P264MB2344.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM%3E&c__parentId=0037R00002vkRKHQA2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using EAC, you can't access the emails with Apex or other automation.  See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323391&type=1&mode=1)

> Einstein Activity Capture (EAC) automatically streams/captures emails
> from your Outlook or Gmail to Salesforce. However, please note that
> the emails streamed/captured in Salesforce using EAC are not created
> as records and are not saved in the database of Salesforce as 'Email
> Messages'